# why regexec() in posix c always return the first match,how can it return all match positions only run once?

Tags: c, regex, linux

Now when I want to return all match positions in str, such as:

```
abcd123abcd123abcd
```

Suppose I want to get all "abcd", I must use regexec(),get the first position:0, 3, then I will use:

```
123abcd123abcd
```

as the new string to use regexec() again, and so on.
I read the manual about regexec(), it says:

```
int regexec(const regex_t *preg, const char *string, size_t nmatch,
               regmatch_t pmatch[], int eflags);
nmatch and pmatch are used to provide information regarding the location of any 
matches.
```

but why doesn't this work?
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int i = 0;
   int res;
   int len;
   char result[BUFSIZ];
   char err_buf[BUFSIZ];
   char* src = argv[1];  

   const char* pattern = "\\<[^,;]+\\>";
   regex_t preg;

   regmatch_t pmatch[10];

   if( (res = regcomp(&preg, pattern, REG_EXTENDED)) != 0)
   {
      regerror(res, &preg, err_buf, BUFSIZ);
      printf("regcomp: %s\n", err_buf);
      exit(res);
   }

   res = regexec(&preg, src, 10, pmatch, REG_NOTBOL);
   //~ res = regexec(&preg, src, 10, pmatch, 0);
   //~ res = regexec(&preg, src, 10, pmatch, REG_NOTEOL);
   if(res == REG_NOMATCH)
   {
      printf("NO match\n");
      exit(0);
   }
   for (i = 0; pmatch[i].rm_so != -1; i++)
   {
      len = pmatch[i].rm_eo - pmatch[i].rm_so;
      memcpy(result, src + pmatch[i].rm_so, len);
      result[len] = 0;
      printf("num %d: '%s'\n", i, result);
   }
   regfree(&preg);
   return 0;
}

./regex 'hello, world'
```

the output:

```
num 0: 'hello'
```

this is my respect outputs:

```
num 0: 'hello'
num 1: 'world'
```

Comment: Show us how you call regexec.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`regexec` performs a regex match. Once a match has been found regexec will return zero (i.e. successful match). The parameter `pmatch` will contain information about that one match. The first array index (i.e. zero) will contain the entire match, subsequent array indices contain information about capture groups/sub-expressions.

To demonstrate:

```
const char* pattern = "(\\w+) (\\w+)";
```

matched on "hello world" will output:

```
num 0: 'hello world'  - entire match
num 1: 'hello'        - capture group 1
num 2: 'world'        - capture group 2
```

(see it in [action](http://codepad.org/X1Qb8kfc))

In most regex environments the behaviour you seek could have been gotten by using the global modifier: /g. Regexec does not provide this modifier as a flag nor does it support modifiers. *You will therefore have to loop while regexec returns zero starting from the last character of the previous match to get all matches*.

The global modifier is also not available using the PCRE library (famous regex C library). The PCRE man pages have this to say about it:

> By calling pcre_exec() multiple times with appropriate arguments, you
>   can mimic Perl's /g option

Comment: What is the difference between that pattern and `"([[:digit:]]+) ([[:digit:]]+)"` ?

Comment: To be clear, your question is not relevant to my answer at all. The regex I used as an example was only for demonstration purposes, as my answer pertains to the workings of `regexec`. But to answer your question: `\w` matches all alphanumeric characters, whereas `[:digit:]` only matches digits.