# Regular expression execution stops at the first match

Tags: c, regex

I have this piece of C code:

```
size_t N_MATCH = 5;
regex_t* finder = (regex_t*)malloc(sizeof(regex_t));
if (0 != regcomp(finder, "_v_[0-9]{1,10}", REG_EXTENDED)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in compiling regular expression\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

and this testing string:

```
char* str = " _v_349853242543543532542 some text blabla _v_134567895324 _v_4332 some other text";
```

But when I execute

```
regexec(&finder, str1, N_MATCH, match, 0);
```

it turns out that `match[i].rm_eo == match[i].rm_so` for every `i` except for `0` (or, in other words, just one match pops out).
I know that that a lot of questons have been asked to solve this issue but I wouldn't be asking this again if I managed to get the results I expect. In particular the following were my (failing) trials:

```
regcomp(finder, "_v_[0-9]{1,10}?", REG_EXTENDED);
regcomp(finder, "(_v_[0-9]{1,10})?", REG_EXTENDED);
regcomp(finder, "_v_[0-9]{1,10}*", REG_EXTENDED);
regcomp(finder, "(_v_[0-9]{1,10})*", REG_EXTENDED);
regcomp(finder, "_v_[0-9]{1,10}+", REG_EXTENDED);
regcomp(finder, "(_v_[0-9]{1,10})+", REG_EXTENDED);
```

Answer (score -1):

`regexec` has no `g` option. You have to call `regexec` in a loop. Look at this example: https://gist.github.com/ianmackinnon/3294587.

See [why regexec() in posix c always return the first match,how can it return all match positions only run once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417454/why-regexec-in-posix-c-always-return-the-first-match-how-can-it-return-all-mat).